# How to load Chinook database in PostgreSQL?

Tags: postgresql, utf-8

Chinook database creation script contains all Western language characters in its text fields so I can't insert them in new PostgreSQL database set on UTF-8

PgAdmin III failed to load the script as well (using SQlite is fine).

Comment: A database with UTF-8 will be able to store "all western language characters". What **exactly** is the error you get? Did you try with `psql` instead of pgAdmin?

Comment: `psql -f Chinook_PostgreSql.sql` worked for me (after creating the database).

Comment: my chinook database is on Encoding='UTF8', LC_COLLATE='en_GB_UTF-8', LC_TYPE= ditto.

Comment: So  I have an error :

Comment: LOG:  database system is ready to accept connections
ERROR:  invalid byte sequence for encoding "UTF8": 0xf4 0x6e 0x69 0x6f
ERROR:  invalid byte sequence for encoding "UTF8": 0xe7 0xe3 0x6f
ERROR:  invalid byte sequence for encoding "UTF8": 0xe1 0x75 0x64
ERROR:  invalid byte sequence for encoding "UTF8": 0xe3 0x6f 0x20

Comment: The SQL script is stored in ISO-8859-1, you need to change your `client_encoding` to reflect that

Answer (score 13):

The short answer to this is to use John Atten's version which is available [here](https://github.com/xivSolutions/ChinookDb_Pg_Modified) on his github.  The rest of this is a short guide on how to run this.

*The following assumes you have already installed and started an instance of PostgreSQL*

## Download the SQL Script

The official versions of the Chinook scripts can be found [here](https://github.com/lerocha/chinook-database).  At time of writing, however, the standards for table and column names currently follow other standards.  John Atten modified the official version to follow PostgreSQL standards, such as using the serial type, and it's available [here](https://github.com/xivSolutions/ChinookDb_Pg_Modified/blob/master/chinook_pg_serial_pk_proper_naming.sql). This is the version I used for this process.

## Create the Database

Run a command to create a DB in which to store the chinook database.  This one is named chinook for simplicity.

```
$ createdb chinook
$
```

## Run the Downloaded File Using psql

psql can be used to run the creation code on the newly created database. If you are operating on a remote database, replace chinook with a connection string.

The -1 runs the entire file as a transaction, ensuring that you won't get a partially completed database on your server.

&>errorlog.txt will store the resulting output to the file errorlog.txt.

```
$ psql chinook -1 -f ~/Path/To/Download/chinook_pg_serial_pk_proper_naming.sql &>errorlog.txt
$
```

## Test the DB to Ensure the Data Loaded

You should now check to see if the data loaded properly. You could use PGAdmin or Postico, but it can easily be checked from the command line using psql's \d command.  Here is an example:

*Once again, if connecting remotely, replace chinook with a connection string*

```
$ psql chinook
psql (10.1)
Type "help" for help.

chinook=# \d
                   List of relations
 Schema |              Name              |   Type   |  Owner
--------+--------------------------------+----------+----------
 public | actor                          | table    | pmitdev1
 public | actor_actor_id_seq             | sequence | pmitdev1
 public | album                          | table    | pmitdev1
 public | album_album_id_seq             | sequence | pmitdev1
 public | artist                         | table    | pmitdev1
 public | artist_artist_id_seq           | sequence | pmitdev1
 public | category                       | table    | pmitdev1
 public | category_category_id_seq       | sequence | pmitdev1
 public | customer                       | table    | pmitdev1
 public | customer_customer_id_seq       | sequence | pmitdev1
 public | employee                       | table    | pmitdev1
 public | employee_employee_id_seq       | sequence | pmitdev1
 public | film                           | table    | pmitdev1
 public | film_actor                     | table    | pmitdev1
 public | film_category                  | table    | pmitdev1
 public | film_film_id_seq               | sequence | pmitdev1
 public | genre                          | table    | pmitdev1
 public | genre_genre_id_seq             | sequence | pmitdev1
 public | invoice                        | table    | pmitdev1
 public | invoice_invoice_id_seq         | sequence | pmitdev1
 public | invoice_line                   | table    | pmitdev1
 public | invoiceline_invoiceline_id_seq | sequence | pmitdev1
 public | media_type                     | table    | pmitdev1
 public | mediatype_mediatype_id_seq     | sequence | pmitdev1
 public | playlist                       | table    | pmitdev1
 public | playlist_playlist_id_seq       | sequence | pmitdev1
 public | playlist_track                 | table    | pmitdev1
...
```